# NGINX regexp or statement for redirect

Tags: regex, nginx, request

I currently have the following NGINX config to redirect all .html requests to the non .html prefix URI if "static" is not in the request URI:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/(?!static/)(.*)\.html) {
    return 301 /$1$is_args$args;
}
```

However, I also want to avoid redirecting to the non .html variant if the request contains "googled" in the URI for the tag manager verification.

I've tried adding `OR statements` in this expression, but I can't seem to figure it out because I lack the knowledge to do something like that in regexp.

How would I add an `OR statement` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you don't want to match for example `/googled123.html`.

You can do:

```
^\/(?!static\/)(?!.*googled)(.*)\.html
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/xhWOte/1)

---

`^` - beginning of string

`(?!static\/)` - don't match string if begins with `static/`

`(?!.*googled)` - don't match string if conains `googled`

`(.*)\.html` - match all without `.html` at the end.